# How to generate Pre Launch report for Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-console

I have a login screen which uses phone authentication for creating account.
I have used Firebase Phone auth for login and also have stored one number for testing purpose.
But don't know how to pass the number and OTP to generate Pre Launch Report.
They are asking for Username, Username Resource ID, Password , Password Resource ID.
Where to find Resource ID for username and password fields in flutter code.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Does not look like it's going to be possible anywhere in the near future: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16921

Comment: Not sure if https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test this link will work for you.

Comment: AFAIK pre-launch report doesn't work for Flutter apps. At least not yet.

Answer (score 1):

In the Google play console at the bottom of the left

1. Click on App content

[image]

2. Click on App access

[image]

3. Click on manage

[image]

4. Click on add new instructions

[image]

Add your all details here it should be test accounts

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
dependencies:
  flutter_runtime_env: ^0.0.4
```

Example:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_runtime_env/flutter_runtime_env.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isInFirebaseTestLab = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    var result = await inFirebaseTestLab();
    setState(() {
      _isInFirebaseTestLab = result;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('is in FirebaseTest Lab'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('is in FirebaseTest Lab: $_isInFirebaseTestLab\n'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---